# Class name for Liquide / Liqp Project in Lucee / Coldfusion,

Tags: java, coldfusion, liquid, lucee

I'm trying to use the Liquid template engine in coldfusion and I'm not sure what "class name" to use when creating the java object in lucee

Relevant Documentation 
Liqp Project: https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp 
Lucee Doc:https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/createobject.html 
Jar File: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.big-o/liqp

```
jLiq = createObject("java","Liquid", expandPath('/app/lib/liqp-0.7.9.jar'))
```

for the 2nd parameter, classname, I've tried many combinations(liqp,Liquid,liqp-0.7.9,liquid.parser,etc), but nothing seems to work, I've inspected the jar file for ideas. Anybody have any ideas on how to reference this java object in coldfuison?

Comment: Have you considered using this CFMl port? https://github.com/rip747/cfml-liquid

Comment: @James Moberg: I had tried that first, but it does not seem to be maintained and I could not bring it into my cfml project with out errors. If this feature proves useful in my app, that I would look at forking that project and bring him up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAR on MVN Repository isn't bundled with its dependencies, so you either put everything into a single fat JAR or specify a folder with all the single JAR files. Once you've done that, you need to create class objects by specifying package + classname:

```
<cfscript>

    LiquidTemplate = createObject("java", "liqp.Template", expandPath("liqp-0.7.9.jar"));

    template = LiquidTemplate.parse("hi {{name}}");
    rendered = template.render({ "name": "tobi" });

    writeOutput(rendered); // hi tobi

</cfscript>
```

As a side note: Why would you use a template engine when you are already on CFML?

Comment: I'm using liquid because I'm developing a Shopify app and there is a large community of Shopify templates written in liquid. For my Shopify app it would be great if I could render some of those liquid templates on the lucee / cfml server side.

Comment: For Reference I used this web site to resolve the dependancies into one download:  https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php